# Why does my SQLite database get deleted when it's changed?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to implement version control into my database. I have following code:

```
if (File.Exists (dbPath)) {
    database = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
    dbVersion = GetDatabaseVersion();
    if (dbVersion != DATABASE_VERSION) {
        CreateDatabase(dbPath);
        database = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        SetDatabaseVersion(DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
} else {
        CreateDatabase(dbPath);
        database = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
        SetDatabaseVersion(DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

When I run the code for the first time `File.Exists (dbPath)` returns false as expected. When I then stop the app and build and deploy again, `File.Exists (dbPath)` returns true (as expected) and the versions get checked. But when I change an entry in the database (not the version) and I build and deploy again `File.Exists (dbPath)` returns false. So I guess the sqlite-file gets deleted when it's changed?

What I want to achieve is that when the sqlite-file is changed, but the version numbers are still the same, the database of the app isn't updated. Only when the versions don't match, it has to be updated.

(It works perfectly for iOS this way, by the way)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you build and deploy the second time (after changing an entry in the database), does the app by any chance get uninstalled from the device before the update is installed?

Comment: Possibly. How do I check this? I thought when you deployed to a phone that already has the app, it just gets updated instead of uninstalled en installed again.

Comment: I think you should check whether your data is wiped after you uninstall you r app.

Comment: Isn't data always wiped after uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult, without access to your debugger, to answer what's going wrong. However, your way of creating and updating your database looks unusual and unnecessarily complicated. You should consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which will allow you a structure like this:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static final int VERION = ...;
   public MyDatabase(Context context) {
      super(context, "mydatabasename", null, VERION);
   }
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("create table...");
      ...
   }
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, intNewVersion) {
      db.execSQL("...")  // whatever you have to change from one version to another
   }
}
```

This works without losing any database files.

Comment: It has to import an existing database. You're right about it being unusual, but it works, so I think I'm gonna leave it that way. The database is part of the Core-part of my crossplatform project so it also has to serve the iOS-side. Having a context as a parameter for example is not possible because of this.

Answer (score 0):

You should tick this box in Visual Studio / Tools / Options / Xamarin / Android settings

[image: Preserve data between deployments]

Comment: Will the data be preserved when a user updates my app from the Play Store for example?

Comment: Yes. It's only a debug option which is not set by default.

Comment: Then you have a problem in your GetDatabaseVersion / SetDatabaseVersion or your other db codes. Files do not vanish magically...

Comment: These methods don't even get called. `File.Exists (dbPath)` returns false when I run the code. I checked the paths and they're always the same.